# Change format of DateTimeReceived (Built-in feature from Microsoft)

Tags: email, powershell, datetime-format

I am working with email and its downloading and i want to set a condition to run a script with If {} only when email is received on the same day.

I do have this 2 lines of script:

```
$datetime = get-date -f yyyMMdd
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::DateTimeReceived, $datetime)
```

First declares today in the format of yyymmdd. 
In order If condition to work, I also need to change format of DateTimeReceived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass date as a parameter to the get-date function, it can convert it to a specified format. You can try something like,

```
$datetime = get-date -f yyyyMMdd
$Sfha = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo((Get-Date ([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::DateTimeReceived) -Format yyyyMMdd), $datetime)
```